# Prove that $H$ is a subset of $G$ if $G$ is a commutative group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a commutative group. Prove that the set of elements of order $2$ together with the identity element, that is $H = \{a \in G : a^2 = e\}$, is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $H$ is a subgroup, you have to show that $H$ is closed under products and inverses, right?. That is, if $a, b\in H$, then $ab\in H$ and $a^{-1}\in H$. That is, if $a$ and $b$ are such that $a^2 = b^2 = e$, then $(ab)^2 = e$ and $(a^{-1})^2 = e$. Can you do that?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
To the others: pretty much same thing said as rogerl, but rogerl was first, so he gets the solve :D

Answer (score 5):

Define $h \colon G \to G$ by $h(x) = x^2$. Then $h$ is a group homomorphism. Thus its kernel $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Whoa! Straightforward but creative! See,these are the kinds of proofs students need to see-it really shows them what all that machinery is for-providing a large toolbox for many alternate proofs of results.At this level,it's not such a big deal-but it certainly becomes increasingly important as the subject becomes steadily deeper and more complicated. It's good to get students used to producing "indirect" proofs like this early.Most of the other proofs produced here so far are "direct" proofs working from the definitions.That's critical of course,but so are proofs like this!

Answer (score 1):

We need only prove, the set contains the identity, it is closed under products and it is closed under inverses.

By construction it contains the identity, since elements of order $2$ are their own inverse it is closed under inverses, now let $a$ and $b$ be of order $2$, then $ab$ is of order two since its inverse is $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ which is $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ since the group is commutative, which is $ab$ since elements of order $2$ are their own inverse, then $(ab)(ab)=1$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $G$ is an abelian group and $p$ is a prime then $H=\{x\in G: x^p=e\}$ is a subgroup.

Let $x$ and $y\in H$. Since every two elements commute in $G$ we have that $|xy|$ divides the least common multiple of $|x|$ and $|y|$. But the lcm is just $1$ or $p$. And it's easy to see that $H$ is closed under inverses.